Selenium Pytest ValueError: setup did not yield a value
I have this test suite (using selenium python pytest) named "test_invoice.py" which has several tests inside it.
Similarly I have other test suites in other python files named "test_admin.py", "test_cash.py" etc with same setup. I run all these suites from a docker image like this:
python -m pytest -v -s --capture=tee-sys --html=report.html --self-contained-html test_invoice.py test_admin.py test_cash.py


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup(request):
  try:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.get(TestData_common.BASE_URL)
    yield
    driver.quit()
except WebDriverException as e:
    print('App seems to be down...> ', e)


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
@pytest.mark.incremental
class Test_app:
  def test_001_login(self):
    assert TestData_common.URL_FOUND, "UAT seems to be down.."
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_click_agree_button()
    assert TestData_common.AGREE_BTN_FOUND, "Unable to click AGREE button.."
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    print('Successfully clicked AGREE button')
    time.sleep(2)

Issue: Sometimes I am getting the below error
request = <SubRequest 'setup' for <Function test_001_login>>
kwargs = {'request': <SubRequest 'setup' for <Function test_001_login>>}

def call_fixture_func(
    fixturefunc: "_FixtureFunc[FixtureValue]", request: FixtureRequest, kwargs
) -> FixtureValue:
    if is_generator(fixturefunc):
        fixturefunc = cast(
            Callable[..., Generator[FixtureValue, None, None]], fixturefunc
        )
        generator = fixturefunc(**kwargs)
        try:
            fixture_result = next(generator)
        except StopIteration:
>               raise ValueError(f"{request.fixturename} did not yield a value") from 
None
E               **ValueError: setup did not yield a value**

I have no idea why this would happen. Is it something wrong with the pytest fixture?
Any help is much appreciated.

The error message "setup did not yield a value" is indicating that the setup fixture function did not yield a value when it was expected to.
The yield keyword in Python is used in a function like a return statement but it returns a generator. In the context of pytest fixtures, yield is used to provide a setup-teardown mechanism for test code. The code before the yield statement is the setup part, and the code after yield is the teardown part.
In your case, the yield statement is within a try block. If an exception occurs before the yield statement, the yield will not be reached, and pytest will raise a ValueError because it expects the fixture to yield a value.
To fix this, you should ensure that the yield statement is always reached. You can do this by moving the yield statement outside of the try block.
So, this might work for you -
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def setup(request):
    driver = None
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        request.cls.driver = driver
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.get(TestData_common.BASE_URL)
    except WebDriverException as e:
        print('App seems to be down...> ', e)
    yield driver
    if driver is not None:
        driver.quit()

